# How should I benchmark a system to determine the overall best architecture choice?

Tags: mongodb, architecture, amazon-ec2, benchmarking, backend

This is a bit of an open ended question, but I'm looking for an open ended answer. I'm looking for a resource that can help explain how to benchmark different systems, but more importantly how to analyze the data and make intelligent choices based on the results.

In my specific case, I have a 4 server setup that includes mongo that serves as the backend for an iOS game. All servers are running Ubuntu 11.10. I've read numerous articles that make suggestions like "if CPU utilization is high, make this change." As a new-comer to backend architecture, I have no concept of what "high CPU utilization" is.

I am using Mongo's monitoring service (MMS), and I am gathering some information about it, but I don't know how to make choices or identify bottlenecks. Other servers serve requests from the game client to mongo and back, but I'm not quite sure how I should be benchmarking or logging important information from them. I'm also using Amazon's EC2 to host all of my instances, which also provides some information.

So, some questions:
What statistics are important to log on a backend setup? (CPU, RAM, etc)

What is a good way to monitor those statistics?

How do I analyze the statistics? (RAM usage is high/read requests are low, etc)

What tips should I know before trying to create a stress-test or benchmarking script for my architecture?

Again, if there is a resource that answers many of these questions, I don't need an explanation here, I was just unable to find one on my own.

If more details regarding my setup are helpful, I can provide those as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: Great question! I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of performance testing as a mini-project that is undertaken because there is a real-world need. Start with the problem to be solved: is the concern that users will have a poor gaming experience if the response time is too slow? Or is the concern that too much money will be spent on unnecessary server hardware?

In short, what is driving the need for the performance testing? This exercise is sometimes called "establishing the problem to be solved." It is about the goal to be achieved-- because if there is not goal, why go through all the work of testing the performance? Establishing the problem to be solved will eventually drive what to measure and how to measure it.

After the problem is established, a next set is to write down what questions have to be answered to know when the goal is met. For example, if the goal is to ensure the response times are low enough to provide a good gaming experience, some questions that come to mind are:

- What is the maximum response time before the gaming experience becomes unacceptably bad?
- What is the maximum response time that is indistinguishable from zero? That is, if 200 ms response time feels the same to a user as a 1 ms response time, then the lower bound for response time is 200 ms.
- What client hardware must be considered? For example, if the game only runs on iOS 5 devices, then testing an original iPhone is not necessary because the original iPhone cannot run iOS 5.

These are just a few question I came up with as examples. A full, thoughtful list might look a lot different.

After writing down the questions, the next step is decide what metrics will provide answers to the questions. You have probably comes across a lot metrics already: response time, transaction per second, RAM usage, CPU utilization, and so on.

After choosing some appropriate metrics, write some test scenarios. These are the plain English descriptions of the tests. For example, a test scenario might involve simulating a certain number of games simultaneously with specific devices or specific versions of iOS for a particular combination of game settings on a particular level of the game.

Once the scenarios are written, consider writing the test scripts for whatever tool is simulating the server work loads. Then run the scripts to establish a baseline for the selected metrics.

After a baseline is established, change parameters and chart the results. For example, if one of the selected metrics is CPU utilization versus the number of of TCP packets entering the server second, make a graph to find out how utilization changes as packets/second goes from 0 to 10,000.

In general, observe what happens to performance as the independent variables of the experiment are adjusted. Use this hard data to answer the questions created earlier in the process.

I did a Google search on "software performance testing methodology" and found a couple of good links:

1. Check out this white paper [Performance Testing Methodology by Johann du Plessis](http://goo.gl/9Qgjk)
2. Have a look at the Methodology section of this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Methodology).